# Pointer to linkedlist randomly changing

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, stack, void-pointers

For one of my school assignments I have to make my own stack library and a POSTFIX calculator.
The calculator has to make use of the stack library and do some calculations.

I am pushing two different numbers to my stack. Number 6 and 3. The header should point to the most recently added node (LIFO). So when 6 is added:

> HEADER -> 6 -> NULL

When 3 is being added:

> HEADER -> 3 -> 6 -> NULL

When I print the value of my header after adding '6' it's good. It's printing 6.
However, when I print the value of my header BEFORE adding '3' it's printing '3'. When it still should print 6.

So a summary of my problem:
When adding another node to my linkedlist, the header suddenly points to the newest node before even changing it.

You may understand me better with some code and debugging results.
Btw: Don't mind the typedefs, I don't like them. My teacher wants us to use it.

```
typedef struct stackObject* pStackObject_t;
typedef struct stackObject
{
    void* obj;
    pStackObject_t next;
} StackObject_t;

typedef struct stackMEta* pStackMeta_t;
typedef struct stackMEta
{
    pStackObject_t stack;
    size_t objsize;
    int numelem; //number of elements
    int handle; //welke stack
    pStackMeta_t next;
} StackMeta_t;

int mystack_push(int handle, void* obj)
{
**DELETED NON RELATED CODE BASED ON FEEDBACK**
    if (currentMeta->handle == handle)
    {
        pStackObject_t newObject = malloc(sizeof(StackObject_t));
        newObject->obj = obj;
        printf("%s%d\n", "Wanting to push int to stack:  ", *(int*)obj);

        //First node
        if (currentMeta->stack == NULL)
        {
            currentMeta->stack = newObject;
            currentMeta->stack->next = NULL;
            printf("%s%d\n", " FIRST Curentmeta->stack pointing to  ", *(int*)currentMeta->stack->obj);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s%d\n", "NOT FIRST Currentmeta->stack pointing to ", *(int*)currentMeta->stack->obj);
            newObject->next = currentMeta->stack;
            currentMeta->stack = newObject;
            printf("%s%d\n", "Currentmeta->stack ", *(int*)currentMeta->stack->obj);
            printf("%s%d\n", "Currentmeta->stack->next ", *(int*)currentMeta->stack->next->obj);
            printf("%s%d\n", "Succesful pushed int to stack:  ", *(int*)currentMeta->stack->obj);
            return 0;
        }
    }
return -1;
}
```

Terminal:

```
Created stack with handle: 1 and objsize 4 bytes
Wanting to push int to stack:  6
FIRST Curentmeta->stack pointing to  6
Wanting to push int to stack:  3
NOT FIRST Currentmeta->stack pointing to 3
Currentmeta->stack 3
Currentmeta->stack->next 3
Succesful pushed int to stack:  3
```

**My unit tests are performing good with this code. My calculator does not, while it's the same function call.**

Comment: Please don't typedef pointers. That serves for nothing but information hiding...

Comment: @Aconcagua It's something my teacher did. He gave us some base code and wanted us to continue on that. I don't like it either, but he does not want any changes to his code.

Comment: This code is not a [mcve] - for completeness, definitions of stack object and stack meta are missing - the latter is irrelevant for minimality, you can drop the while loop and if (handle) condition and just have one single stack. Maybe you want to have a look at [ask] as well.

Comment: OK, but you'd still have the option not to use pointer typedefs in *your own* code...

Comment: @Aconcagua where do you see a typedef in my own code? I am using the typedefs of my teacher.

Comment: Your complaining about my question, but your own answers aren't even related to my question.

Comment: Actually, I cannot reproduce the error (GCC 8.1, Linux, slightly minimalised code). So without [mcve] (which includes, too, how you call your function!) it won't be possible to help you.

Comment: I commented only, I did not answer. If you are using typedefs of your teacher, you need to include them here. There's little use in letting us guess them.

Comment: @Aconcagua deleted the while loop as you wanted and added the typedefs.

Comment: Already better... Getting back to mcve: What we need to help you is a piece of code we can copy from here, paste into our own IDE and can compile and run it without modification (if at all, missing system headers, if obviously unrelated, might be missing) - keyword "complete". Would that work with your code??? Minimality: It is not helpful if you make us check already working code, so you should get rid of. My removal of the while loop, though, possibly was a bit too short sighted. It depends on how you call your function (maybe you used different handles?)

Comment: Don't be angry with me - point is: I have to make lots of assumptions (create the meta objects myself, call your functions, etc). But by doing so I cannot reproduce the error. And if I cannot, well, how should I be able to help you?

Comment: @Aconcagua If I would paste the code for my calculator here, it would be too much again. I am simply calling the function with mystack_push(1, &tempInt); I do that twice. In my unit tests it's working. In my calculator not. Do you want me to paste the whole calculator?

Comment: I would post your calculator since it's the part that is _not_ working. Obviously, there is something about it. Either _it_ has an error, _or_ it is uncovering an error in your `mystack_push` that is not covered by your unit tests (i.e. when your issue is found, add a unit test that covers the discovered case). Also, I looked at the edit history and I believe the `while` in `mystack_push` is _critical_ to proper operation.

Comment: @Gigitex No, I don't. But we rely on code that let's us ***reproduce*** the error. So try removing from your code step by step *anything* that is unrelated (of course have a backup before doing so!). Maybe you find the error yourself during this process... If not, then post here what still remained.

Comment: @Aconcagua ah, don't have time for that. Just nevermind then. It's just a simple call with two integers. The code here is already minimalized. Normally I should use multiple stacks, I am using just one. I am also using only 2 objects, instead of 50.  My unit tests have the same call, it works there. I have had the same problem a year ago aswell. I don't think the code is the problem, but my image. Classmates have the same problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: By the way: Have you tried *debugging* your code? This might reveal the error to you as well.

Comment: I did with prints. I also tested the same input values in another code with the same library and got the right results. It's like the file is corrupt or something, i don't know. GDB does not help either. I will just give up.

Comment: As your problem concerns the stack push function, the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be a simple but complete framework that tests the use of the function without regard to the calculator application. If the function can be shown to work properly, then the problem is caused somewhere else in the code. It is not the function which you should minimalise (and the edited post is now useless to demonstrate) but its container.

Comment: I will just delete and give up. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was working 50/50. Using the same input values in another program resulted in good things.

I changed the code to this:

```
 pStackObject_t newObject = malloc(sizeof(StackObject_t));
 newObject->obj = malloc(sizeof(currentMeta->objsize));
 memcpy(newObject->obj, obj, currentMeta->objsize);
```

Now it's working fine. The previous code was somehow using the old values, while it was already out of scope. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Fine that you found the error. It's a problem of ownership then. We cannot know if you did `int n = 10; push(&n); n = 12; push(&n);` - which obviously was the case - or if you did it properly (having separate variables for each or having `malloc`ed memory for each) - and that's why it is so important to have a [mcve]! For me, I saw your code, and it was natural for me to use `n` + `m` variables, so missed the possibility that you could be using a single variable...

Comment: Be aware, though, that you now have to `free` the memory on deletion of list nodes, too!!! (Just for the case if need be...).

Comment: Aha, don't worry the program is already memory leak free haha thanks to valgrind!